# Cannot get the temporal plugin in the plugin manager

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, temporal-controller

I am using QGIS 3.4.8 and I want to animate time series data using temporal controller but I couldn't get the temporal plugin in the plugin manager list. I couldn't install in the software. What might be my problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Temporal Controller is available from QGIS 3.14 onwards. For older versions of QGIS, the Time Manager plugin provides a similar functionality.

Useful Links:

- [TimeManager is dead, long live the Temporal Controller!](https://anitagraser.com/2020/05/10/timemanager-is-dead-long-live-the-temporal-controller/)
- [Animating Time Series Data](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/animating_time_series.html)